# Managing users BPMN/Activity for multiple tenants (departments)

Tags: spring, activiti, bpmn

I have several process definitions in BPMN and using Activity to start them. Process definitions includes users that are responsible to perform tasks. Internet full of examples how to manage such schemes.

But now I need start multiple process instances of the same process against multiple departments. Each department has near the same organization structure, but persons are not the same. For example *After shipping goods head of department must send the report to customer*. In this case *head of department* behaves the same but each time it is different person. And following BPMN definition cannot manage this:

```
<resourceAssignmentExpression>
    <formalExpression>head</formalExpression>
</resourceAssignmentExpression>
```

Because each department has own head.

So my question: How to manage user in separate instances of BPMN process?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I was building this solution, I would pass the department into the process instance as a businessKey on startup.
Then, I would use a task listener attached to the assign event to determine who the task should be assigned to based on the business key.
Other advantages of this approach are that the business key will be persisted in history giving you the opportunity to report on instances by department.

Hope this helps.